# Excel list vaildation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a couple of dropdown list. they contains a simple Y/N combination.

I have several external spreadsheets that I have to copy and paste data from . However the Y/N column in the external spreadshhets may contain the y/n in lowercase. or Yes/NO text.

If the text value is y/n or YES/NO I like it to conform to the list value Y/N

I tried to add a formula to the cells themselves but I get a circular reference error.

I then attempted a VBA script:

```
       Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    Dim cell As Range

              If Target.Column = 9 Then


                    If (UCase(ActiveCell.Value) = "YES") Then
                       ActiveCell.Value = "Y"

                    ElseIf UCase(ActiveCell.Value) = "NO" Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = "N"

                    ElseIf UCase(Target.Value) = Empty Then
                        ActiveCell.Value = "N"

                    Else
                        ActiveCell.Value = UCase(ActiveCell.Value)
                    End If

               End If    

Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occured -  error  " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

    End Sub
```

This almost works it change the value from YES to Y etc and checks for upper case but it crashes excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the vbs script seem to be the way to go. I had to add 
the Application.EnableEvents  to the script once I did that excel stop crashing and I got the results i'm looking for.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Dim cell As Range

     If Target.Column = 9 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

                   For Each cell In Target

                            If (UCase(cell.Value) = "YES") Then
                               cell.Value = "Y"

                            ElseIf UCase(cell.Value) = "NO" Then
                                cell.Value = "N"

                            ElseIf UCase(cell.Value) = Empty Then
                                cell.Value = "N"

                            Else
                                cell.Value = UCase(cell.Value)
                            End If

                   Next cell

                   Application.EnableEvents = True

            End If


Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "An error occured -  error  " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```